# Accessing values inside <td> elements containing text values from server inside a <div> tag

Tags: javascript, html

Inspecting Element Representation:

```
<tr id = "">
<td>
<div> XYZ1 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div> XYZ2 </div>
</td>
<td>
<div> XYZ3 </div>
</td>
```

I have to access values of XYZ inside the Console to further continue with my task.

I tried this:

```
console.log($(td).parent().closest('div').val());
```

and

```
console.log( $(td).find('div').val();
```

But it returns 'undefined'.

Any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an array of all the values like this:

```
var values = $('td > div').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();
console.log(values); // ["XYZ1", "XYZ2", "XYZ3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`val()` is looking for the element value (such as input fields). you are actually looking for the text inside the element and should use `text()`

try:

```
console.log($(td).next('div').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` will never return a valid value here. Use `.text()` or `.html()` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at selecting with jquery in some depth, especially .next() and .find() methods.

Answer (score 0):

try this, that should log you the div element:`console.log($('td>div'));`

Comment: It returned something like:
[prevObject: v.fn.v.init[1], context: document, selector: "td>div", constructor: function, init: function…]

Comment: I would assume these are dynamically loaded in, can you provide more code?